# How do i convert an Iostr into a string?

Tags: python

(it's probably a dumb question)
How do i convert a Io string into a normal string?
I needed to write and access line per line of a string but now i want to use the find function to scrape some information from it.
I wasn't able to find anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = StringIO('abc')
str_a = a.read()
```